# Why does my Thread from Alphabet to morseAlphabet not work?

Tags: mapthread

I have

```
Thread[Alphabet[] -> morseAlphabet[]]
```

But I don't get morse code for each letter, instead:

```
{"a" -> morseAlphabet[], "b" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "c" -> morseAlphabet[], "d" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "e" -> morseAlphabet[], "f" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "g" -> morseAlphabet[], "h" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "i" -> morseAlphabet[], "j" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "k" -> morseAlphabet[], "l" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "m" -> morseAlphabet[], "n" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "o" -> morseAlphabet[], "p" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "q" -> morseAlphabet[], "r" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "s" -> morseAlphabet[], "t" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "u" -> morseAlphabet[], "v" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "w" -> morseAlphabet[], "x" -> morseAlphabet[], 
 "y" -> morseAlphabet[], "z" -> morseAlphabet[]}
```

So yes, I am a learner. I imagine I am not indexing right. Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems you are missing a definition of `morseAlphabet`.

Comment: You can look at this information about moris code in Mathematica:  https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/computational-audio/create-and-decode-a-morse-code-signal.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems OP has a definition like this:

```mathematica
morseAlphabet[] := {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."}
```

Then here is the result of OP's code :

```mathematica
Thread[Alphabet[] -> morseAlphabet[]]

(* {"a" -> ".-", "b" -> "-...", "c" -> "-.-.", "d" -> "-..", 
 "e" -> ".", "f" -> "..-.", "g" -> "--.", "h" -> "....", "i" -> "..", "j" -> ".---", "k" -> "-.-", "l" -> ".-..", "m" -> "--", "n" -> "-.", "o" -> "---", "p" -> ".--.", "q" -> "--.-", "r" -> ".-.", 
 "s" -> "...", "t" -> "-", "u" -> "..-", "v" -> "...-", "w" -> ".--", "x" -> "-..-", "y" -> "-.--", "z" -> "--.."} *)
```

---

Using the WL code from ["Create and Decode a Morse Code Signal"](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/computational-audio/create-and-decode-a-morse-code-signal.html):

```mathematica
code = <|"a" -> ".-", "b" -> "-...", "c" -> "-.-.", "d" -> "-..", 
  "e" -> ".", "f" -> "..-.", "g" -> "--.", "h" -> "....", "i" -> "..",
   "j" -> ".---", "k" -> "-.-", "l" -> ".-..", "m" -> "--", 
  "n" -> "-.", "o" -> "---", "p" -> ".--.", "q" -> "--.-", 
  "r" -> ".-.", "s" -> "...", "t" -> "-", "u" -> "..-", "v" -> "...-",
   "w" -> ".--", "x" -> "-..-", "y" -> "-.--", "z" -> "--..", 
  "1" -> ".----", "2" -> "..---", "3" -> "...--", "4" -> "....-", 
  "5" -> ".....", "6" -> "-....", "7" -> "--...", "8" -> "---..", 
  "9" -> "----.", "0" -> "-----", "." -> ".-.-.-", "," -> "--..--", 
  "!" -> "-.-.--", "?" -> "..--.."|>
```

Here we thread into rules:

```mathematica
Thread[Alphabet[] -> Values[KeyTake[code, Alphabet[]]]]

(* {"a" -> ".-", "b" -> "-...", "c" -> "-.-.", "d" -> "-..", "e" -> ".", "f" -> "..-.", "g" -> "--.", "h" -> "....", "i" -> "..", 
 "j" -> ".---", "k" -> "-.-", "l" -> ".-..", "m" -> "--", "n" -> "-.", "o" -> "---", "p" -> ".--.", "q" -> "--.-", "r" -> ".-.", 
 "s" -> "...", "t" -> "-", "u" -> "..-", "v" -> "...-", "w" -> ".--", "x" -> "-..-", "y" -> "-.--", "z" -> "--.."}*)
```

Comment: Thank you, and would there be a way to use the morseAlphabet (you were right, I did not define it)? When I do ```Thread[Alphabet[] -> morseAlphabet[]]``` I don't get the mapping you get, but ```{"a" -> {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", 
    "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", 
    ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", 
    "--.."}[]``` and so on. I think I am missing something.

Comment: It seems you have not defined `morseAlphabet` correctly. Quit the kernel, then copy, paste, and execute the code in my answer.